# How to fix 'ARGUMENTS_NOT_ALLOWED' error Realm SDK for Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, mongodb, kotlin, realm

I am using MongoDB to save data from my Android app which I am developing with Kotlin Jetpack Compose. I am using MongoClient to access the database and save the data, but when I try to insert a Document I get this error:

> Error: ARGUMENTS_NOT_ALLOWED(realm::app::ServiceError:13) : insert not permitted

This is my code where I login and try to insert a Document into MongoDB Cluster:

```
Realm.init(this)

    val appID : String = "my-app-id";
    app = App(
        AppConfiguration.Builder(appID)
        .build())

    app?.loginAsync(Credentials.emailPassword(email, password)) {
        if (it.isSuccess) {
            val user: User? = app?.currentUser()


            val client = user?.getMongoClient("mongodb-atlas")
            val db = client?.getDatabase("tracker")
            val coll = db?.getCollection("User")

            val doc = Document("_id", UUID.randomUUID().toString()).append("name", "Besart")
            coll?.insertOne(doc)?.getAsync {
                if(it.isSuccess){
                    ...
                }else{
                    Log.e("ERROR", "${it.error.errorCode}")
                    it.error.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Failed to log in. Error: ${it.error}")
        }
    }
```

This is Users schema I created from MongoDB UI:

```
{

 "title": "User",
  "properties": {
    "_id": {
      "bsonType": "objectId"
    },
    "name": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

The user has full access to the database:
[image]

Comment: On what line does that error occur, and have you verified the vars are correctly populated and valid?

Comment: The error is thrown when I try to `insertOne` in the `else` statement

Comment: I would guess that one of the parameters is out of scope. Try changing the code around a bit and see if the vars resolve to valid data. I would also take a look at this [Example](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/v4.3/usage-examples/insertOne/?_ga=2.35018785.1492361816.1657561059-586838695.1657561058#example) for insertOne to see a suggested design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Changing BSON type of the field in the collection scheme (to `object` type in my case) helped me to fix similar issue

[image]